# Backup from an external USB-storage plugged in a FritzBox

Tags: backup, usb-storage, fritzbox

I'm using an external USB-disk connected to a Fritz!Box for storing data. The data is accessible to all computers in the LAN by a share - this works fine! But now I want to backup the data from this external USB-Disk.

Is there a way / tool / command to automatically backup the files stored on this Fritz!Box external USB-drive to e.g. an NAS or to an of-site cloud solution?

(After searching a lot, I only found the other way: Storing a backup to this external USB-disk, but that's already solved by another solution)

Some details:

- Fritz!Box 7362 SL
- FritzOS newest Version 7.12
- USB-Disk 1TB HGST Travelstar
- Share smb://fritz.nas accessible form all PCs
- NAS: Synology DS107+ with 4TB Disk (already existing in our LAN for client backup)
- Cloud: AWS ideal via SSH rsync

Comment: Which device would you like to use to run this backup script?

Comment: good question: ideal it works on the FritzBox pushing the data (like on all clients the backup-software pushes to the NAS). Another way would be on NAS pulling the data from the FritzBox. I don't want to place some script/tool on an addition computer like a client or RasPi to pull from FritzBox and push to NAS